# Валидация вводимых данных в  Textbox на jquery + asp.net webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net-webforms, sharepoint

Доброго времени суток. Не могу найти примеров валидации данных на клиентской стороне на jquery (например, плагином validation), вроде все просто, но валидация не проходит.

Answer (score 1):

Повесь на поле событие, например, `blur()` (потеря фокуса), и проверяй с помощью регульных выражений.